# Live audio transmission between mobile and Esp8266 NodeMcu

Tags: websocket, arduino, iot, esp8266, esp8266wifi

[image]I am trying to transmit my voice live from my mobile phone to esp8266. I am using web browser as client interface and Wifi as connection.
I heard that this can be done with websocket ,
what I need is how to write the code in the arduino

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, maybe this doesn't answer the problem. but maybe from the basics in [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/Nl_FYRyxnUY) you can get ideas to apply in your projects.
required library => https://github.com/earlephilhower/ESP8266Audio

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).